# X, Y Coordinates class in Lazarus (Delphi-like)

Tags: object-oriented, coordinate-system, pascal

After I've now officially announced, that I'm discontinuing my color picker for Windows, I'm about to embark on a journey through Linux development.

---

I was quite strong in **[Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi)** on *Windows*, and see no valid reason to focus - not that I'm not trying to, in quite many languages - mainly on development in **[Lazarus](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/)** on *Linux*, as of now in major version 2.0. Without wanting to pay for an IDE, I just decided to stick with Lazarus.

---

That's enough for starters. Let's get to my question.

I haven't developed in Delphi since version XE6 dated 2014, so I need to refresh my knowledge, and this question is about the very core of the new color picker for Linux. Feel free to add any answer or comment. If I did the smallest error, I need to know. The first class I've written is meant for keeping track of X, Y coordinates (of the mouse cursor), I generalized it.

---

```delphi
unit Coords;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes;

type
    // Flexible X, Y coordinates object class.
    TCoords = class(TObject)

    // these declarations are accessible within this unit only
    private
        // this is the variable we are working with
        FCoords: TPoint;
        // property for this function is unnecessary, but I like it as it is
        function IsInitialized: Boolean;

    // these declarations are visible and accessible to all
    public
        // this creates instance of TCoords initialized to PointOutOfReach
        constructor Create; reintroduce; overload;
        // this creates instance of TCoords initialized to user given point
        constructor Create(const ACoords: TPoint); overload;
        // this creates instance of TCoords initialized to user given coordinates
        constructor Create(const AX, AY: Integer); overload;
        // this indicates if instance was initialized or not by the user
        property Initialized: Boolean read IsInitialized;
        // this works directly with private FCoords variable storing coordinates
        property P: TPoint read FCoords write FCoords;
        // these two are shortcuts for X, Y coordinates' direct access
        property X: Integer read FCoords.X write FCoords.X;
        property Y: Integer read FCoords.Y write FCoords.Y;

    end;

implementation

var
  // this gets initialized when loading this unit
  PointOutOfReach: TPoint;

constructor TCoords.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;
    // since called without argument, we have to ensure,
    // there are some corner-case coordinates, so that we can
    // differentiate between a [0:0] and uninitialized state
    FCoords := PointOutOfReach;
end;

constructor TCoords.Create(const ACoords: TPoint);
begin
    inherited Create;
    FCoords := ACoords;
end;

constructor TCoords.Create(const AX, AY: Integer);
begin
    inherited Create;
    FCoords := Point(AX, AY);
end;

function TCoords.IsInitialized: Boolean;
begin
    // this returns True in case FCoords has been initialized
    // initialized means here for the FCoords point to be different from PointOutOfReach
    // achieved either by calling `Create(APoint)`, or later overwriting PointOutOfReach
    Result := FCoords <> PointOutOfReach;
end;

initialization

    // initialize PointOutOfReach to "impossible" coordinates when loading unit
    PointOutOfReach := Point(MAXINT, MAXINT);

end.
```

---

### Edit

Since there is not yet a review, I could edit, that I've added one useful function:

declaration

```delphi
// this converts the coordinates to string (default delimiter set to colon)
function ToString(const Delimiter: string = ':'): string; reintroduce;
```

definition

```delphi
function TCoords.ToString(const Delimiter: string = ':'): string;
begin
    // setting empty result for debugging purposes solely
    Result := '';
    // this can happen only if constructor TCoords.Create; has been used
    if not IsInitialized then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.ToString: `FCoords: TPoint` member has not yet been initialized');
    end;
    // it does not make sence for the user to input empty delimiter
    // as that would lead to concatenating XY without any delimiter
    if Delimiter.IsEmpty then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.ToString: `Delimiter: string` argument is empty');
    end;
    // example: X=0, Y=1, Delimiter=' x ' would return '0 x 1'
    Result := FCoords.X.ToString + Delimiter + FCoords.Y.ToString;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```delphi
> unit Coords;
>      ^
> ```

If you noticed the big letter, let me tell you this was a bad start. I saved the unit file as `Coords.pas`, which lead to a series of various files' edits. Not recommended. Stick to lower-case:

```delphi
unit coords;
```

---

> ```delphi
> TCoords = class(TObject)
> ```

`TObject` class is implicit, so it may be omitted:

```delphi
TCoords = class
```

---

> ```delphi
> private
> ```

This protects members on unit scope only. Since I intended to protect members on class scope, I now use:

```delphi
strict private
```

---

> ```delphi
> function IsInitialized: Boolean;
> ```

This is not only unnecessary but it also clouded my judgment as for not having any *getters* nor *setters*, I now have:

```delphi
function GetCoordX: Integer;
function GetCoordY: Integer;
function GetPoint: TPoint;
procedure SetCoordX(const NewX: Integer);
procedure SetCoordY(const NewY: Integer);
procedure SetPoint(const NewPoint: TPoint);
```

Definitions can be found at the bottom of this answer.

---

```delphi
// ...
```

Excessive commenting I found not helpful, only making a mess.

---

I was not properly checking the input in all cases. This was remedied (I hope). Also, raising exceptions in case of error proved helpful.

---

The `initialization` section along with the `PointOutOfReach` variable can be deleted, the more code I have, the less of its usefulness I saw, using structures like this one has proven more helpful:

```delphi
if (ACoords.X = MAXINT) or (ACoords.Y = MAXINT) then
begin
    raise Exception.Create('TCoords.Create: You cannot initialize `FCoords: TPoint` member to MAXINT coordinates');
end;
```

---

### Code after review

```delphi
unit coords;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes, SysUtils;

type
    TCoords = class
    strict private
        FCoords: TPoint;
        function GetCoordX: Integer;
        function GetCoordY: Integer;
        function GetPoint: TPoint;
        procedure SetCoordX(const NewX: Integer);
        procedure SetCoordY(const NewY: Integer);
        procedure SetPoint(const NewPoint: TPoint);
    public
        constructor Create; reintroduce; overload;
        constructor Create(const ACoords: TPoint); overload;
        constructor Create(const ACoordX, ACoordY: Integer); overload;
        function ToString(const Delimiter: string = ':'): string; reintroduce;
        property X: Integer read GetCoordX write SetCoordX;
        property Y: Integer read GetCoordY write SetCoordY;
        property P: TPoint read GetPoint write SetPoint;
    end;

implementation

constructor TCoords.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;

    FCoords := Point(MAXINT, MAXINT);
end;

constructor TCoords.Create(const ACoords: TPoint);
begin
    inherited Create;

    if (ACoords.X = MAXINT) or (ACoords.Y = MAXINT) then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.Create: You cannot initialize `FCoords: TPoint` member to MAXINT coordinates');
    end;

    FCoords := ACoords;
end;

constructor TCoords.Create(const ACoordX, ACoordY: Integer);
begin
    inherited Create;

    if (ACoordX = MAXINT) or (ACoordY = MAXINT) then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.Create: You cannot initialize `FCoords: TPoint` member to MAXINT coordinates');
    end;

    FCoords := Point(ACoordX, ACoordY);
end;

function TCoords.GetCoordX: Integer;
begin
    if FCoords.X = MAXINT then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.GetCoordX: `FCoords.X: Integer` is equal to MAXINT. It has not been initialized yet');
    end;

    Result := FCoords.X;
end;

function TCoords.GetCoordY: Integer;
begin
    if FCoords.Y = MAXINT then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.GetCoordY: `FCoords.Y: Integer` is equal to MAXINT. It has not been initialized yet');
    end;

    Result := FCoords.Y;
end;

procedure TCoords.SetCoordX(const NewX: Integer);
begin
    if NewX = MAXINT then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.SetCoordX: `NewX: Integer` value cannot equal MAXINT');
    end;

    FCoords.X := NewX;
end;

procedure TCoords.SetCoordY(const NewY: Integer);
begin
    if NewY = MAXINT then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.SetCoordY: `NewY: Integer` value cannot equal MAXINT');
    end;

    FCoords.Y := NewY;
end;

function TCoords.GetPoint: TPoint;
begin
    Result := Point(GetCoordX, GetCoordY);
end;

procedure TCoords.SetPoint(const NewPoint: TPoint);
begin
    SetCoordX(NewPoint.X);
    SetCoordY(NewPoint.Y);
end;

function TCoords.ToString(const Delimiter: string = ':'): string;
begin
    if Delimiter.IsEmpty then
    begin
        raise Exception.Create('TCoords.ToString: `Delimiter: string` argument is empty');
    end;

    // example: X=0, Y=1, Delimiter=' x ' would return '0 x 1'
    Result := GetCoordX.ToString + Delimiter + GetCoordY.ToString;
end;

end.
```